# HKT manifolds with non trivial canonical bundle

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, complex-geometry, complex-manifolds

A compact HKT manifold is a hyperhermitian manifold $(M,I,J,K,g)$ such that either $\partial (\omega_J+i\omega_K)=0$ (if endomorphisms act on the left on the tangent space and $\partial$ is taken with respect to $I$) or, equivalently, the three Bismut connections for hermitian structures $(I,g)$, $(J,g)$, $(K,g)$ are all the same.

**My question** is related to the situation when the canonical bundle (with respect to $I$) is non trivial$^1$ (holomorphically). Can it happen that $\mathcal{K}_M$ has many section or it always has no sections at all, like for example for Hopf surfaces?

**The second question** is whether the answer is know for example for homogeneous examples of hypercomplex manifolds due to Joyce, $SU(3)$ for instance?

$1.$ From the work of M. Verbitsky it is know that a compact HKT manifold has a trivial canonical bundle iff the holonomy of the Obata connection is reduced to $Sl_n(\mathbb{H})$.

Answer (score 1):

For $SU(3)$ and Hopf it is the anticanonical
bundle which has many sections. In other
examples of Joyce, it is also the anticanonical
bundle or its powers. For nilmanifolds, the
canonical bundle is holomorphically trivial.

I think I know how to construct a compact HKT manifold
with many sections of the canonical bundle,
(drop me a email to verbit@impa.br, if you
are still interested).

All the best
Misha